# how to write simple select query with where clause in django object view.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am very new to Django and want to ask one doubt that how to write simple select query with where clause in django view.py?

e.g. I have a sqlite db with a column name "result" and I want to fetch the result in view.py by object.filter or similar thing like that.

SQL Query-
select result from polls_testreults where css_class="event-info" and requestId="201456"

What I am trying to achieve-

reslink=    TestReults.objects.values('result',flat=True).filter(requestId=checkbox)

I am not getting any output in reslink and I think query is also wrong.
kindly help me out

Comment: had you done that thing , please help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
test_results = TestResult.objects.filter(css_class="event-info", requestId="201456")
```

You need to go through the basic django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/) first, I believe you would figure out a lot more than this once you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shang wang..but will it give particular row with "result" or it will behave as select * from polls_testreults where css_class="event-info" and requestId="201456" instead of select result from polls_testreults where css_class="event-info" and requestId="201456"

Comment: Yea, just on top of my answer, do `test_results = test_results.values_list('result', flat=True).distinct()`.

Comment: can;t i join these both ?

Comment: hi Shang Wang, I think I got the answer -   test_results = TestReults.objects.values_list('result', flat=True).filter(css_class="event-info", requestId=checkbox)... checkbox is the variable which I am trying to pass, in django console its showing the expected output. Thanks for the guidance